# How to implement additional keypress for mouseevent handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanted to implement `mousemove` on `ctrl + mousemove` by **Default** `click` handler will be there always.

**points:**

- `click handler` will always will be there
- whenever `user` want to get details on  `mouseover` then he has to hold `ctrl` i,e  `mouseover + ctrl` otherwise **default** `click` will work
- how can i implement `mousemover + crl` ?

**problem(s) in current code:**

1. whenever i `click` on row and go to detail view, random `mouseover` is `triggered` loosing the `active` state and data.

**here is my codepen:**  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEwopd

```js
$(function(){
   $('table tbody tr').on('mouseover',function(){     $('table tbody tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
     var data = $(this).data('column');
       $('#dataView').html('<p style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;">'+data+'</p>'); 
   });
  
  $('table tbody tr').on('click',function(){
     $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
       var data = $(this).data('column');
       $('#dataView').html('<p style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;">'+data+'</p>'); 
   });
});
```

```css
table{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
}

table thead,tbody td{
  padding:20px;
}

#container{
  width:100%;
}

#bothwrapper{
  max-height:210px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:65%;
  float:left;
  outline:1px solid #999;
}

#dataView{
  float:right;
  width:35%;
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  outline:1px solid #999;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}

/* table tbody tr:hover{
  background:skyblue;
} */

.active{
  background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="bothwrapper">
  <table border="1">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>name1</th>
         <th>name2</th>
         <th>name3</th>
         <th>name4</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr data-column="first-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
        <tr data-column="second-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
        <tr data-column="third-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
       <tr data-column="fourth-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
       <tr data-column="fifth-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
       <tr data-column="sixth-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
        <tr data-column="seventh-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
      <tr data-column="eighth-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
        <tr data-column="nineth-coulmn">
         <td>hello1</td>
         <td>hello2</td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div id="dataView">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to archive the result like below

Change a little bit of your code.

This code only change the row color when user press CTRL and hover.

And the click code still working to change the color too.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').on('mouseover',function(evt){   

        // Check if ctrl pressed  
        if (evt.ctrlKey){
            $('table tbody tr').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active').css("cursor","pointer"); 
            var data = $(this).data('column');
            $('#dataView').html('<p style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;">'+data+'</p>'); 
        }else{
            $(this).css("cursor","default"); 

        }
    });

    $('table tbody tr').on('click',function(){

        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }else{
            $('table tbody tr').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        var data = $(this).data('column');
        $('#dataView').html('<p style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;">'+data+'</p>'); 
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/synz/b4vgz609/